# openLDAP Client Config for CentOS 6

Tags: authentication, centos6, openldap, passwd

I have been trying to get the users on the LDAP server to get authenticated over centOS 6 clients, but, the client will not accept the passwords of the LDAP users.

I have Ubuntu Systems which successfully does the job, with the basic settings.

How do I enable LDAP users to be able to log-in to the CentOS servers, and also be able to change their LDAP passwords from the CentOS clients?

I have followed the tutorial mentioned on this link
http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=ldap&f=2

and a few more that i found over google.

Comment: Basically what i want to do is, be able to achieve what has been achieved in Ubuntu in the following 2 links

http://www.supportsages.com/blog/2012/06/ldap-configuration-for-user-and-group-centralization-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-part-1/

http://www.supportsages.com/blog/2012/06/ldap-configuration-for-user-and-group-centralization-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-part-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After conducting a lot of research, i finally was able to get LDAP installed on CentOS, and make it as my Central Authentication Server.

this is what i did.

### #

SERVER

### #

yum -y install openldap openldap-clients openldap-servers *cyrus* nss-pam-ldapd pam_ldap

yum -y install nscd

cd /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/

vi olcDatabse*

### edited all the olcDatabase files which had dn.base: dc=my-domain,dc=com to dc=example,dc=com

### and cnRoot to cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

slappasswd -h {SHA}

password:

re-type password:

{SHA}htbwnsaklreh=

### copy the output and paste it in olcDatabase*bdb.ldif

### olcRootPW: {SHA}htbwnsaklreh=

cd /etc/sysconfig

vi ldap

### change SLAPD_LDAPS=no to yes

### start log for slapd

echo "local4.* /var/log/slapd.log" >> /etc/rsyslog.conf

service rsyslog restart

/etc/init.d slapd start

cp /usr/share/openldap-servers/DB_CONFIG.example /var/lib/ldap/DB_CONFIG

chown -R ldap:ldap /var/lib/ldap/DB_CONFIG

chown -R ldap:ldap /etc/openldap/slapd.d

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state new -m tcp -p tcp --dport 389 -j ACCEPT

### #

CLIENT and Tree initialization

### #

for the client config, i followed the steps mentioned by Mr. Adrian, in his post on here

http://wiki.centos.org/AdrianHall/CentralizedLDAPAuth

#### THIS SHOULD HELP YOU SET-UP openLDAP on centOS 6 as well as CentOS6.4, i have tried it on these two versions Personally.

Answer (score 0):

Quick reply with a few things to check:

- Ensure you have proper LDAP server(s) specified. If using FQDN, ensure it properly resolves to LDAP server on the client.
- Double check LDAP tree suffixes, etc.
- Check that you are getting proper info via command-line tools from the server
- Check for proper ports being open on both the client and the server

Also I would recommend using SSL with older LDAPv2 servers (slapd v1.2.x). Or use latest slapd 2.x for LDAPv3 with SSL out of the box.

Comment: i have the LDAP server with proper FQDN - something like dc=example,dc=com...

LDAP tree suffixes are proper, I know this, coz i have been able to authenticate Ldap users from Ubuntu Client Systems...

on the CentOS system(the one troubling me)- command - id test1 --gives necessary information (test1 is a user on LDAP and not a local client user)...

Comment: port 389 is opened, anyways, i have flushed the IPtables on the client and server, so this should not be a problem

Comment: i do not want to use SSL, as of now, i just need to get the users working, SSL was not setup on the server, so it would be a hectic issue, considering i will have to setup the server again (which was very difficult in the first place)

Comment: Make sure to save the IPtables and restart IPtables just in case. I've been bit by IPtables a few time before even tho I have made the necessary changes to rules. However if you are able to query LDAP from the CentOS client, then firewall isn't the likely reason. Re-check configs. Would be helpful if you posted the settings that you have. Someone might spot the issue.

Comment: Use or not use SSL, but be aware that without SSL or some other way of securely sending user credentials, the information may be visible to others. Just a suggestion. Proceed at your own risk.

Comment: Check logs for error message on both client and server. These might contain hints.

Comment: i will restart the iptables, currently the deployment is on VM's in my laptop, will post the configs, ASAP